# unable to use priority annotation

Tags: selenium, testng

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWLeI.png  While I am trying to use 'priority' with the @Test annotation.
Showing as "The attribute priority is undefined for the annotation type Test".  "priority" is not listed in the available fixes list also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're using the wrong test class. You've imported org.junit.test which does not support the @priority parameter. Instead use `import org.testng.annotations.Test`